# Calling a Method C

Tags: c

Having some trouble calling a method in my main method. I am just wanting to obtain a word at random from the array in the "init" method, find its length and then print all the information. (Random Number Generated, Which Word that correlates too and it length). Just starting out with C, all help is appreciated.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "hangman.h"

void init(char* word);


int main(void)
{
   char word[MAX_WORD_LEN + 1];
   unsigned wrongGuesses = 0;
   int guessedLetters[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
   };


init(); 



   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



void init(char* word)
{
   const char* words[NUM_WORDS] = {
      "array",      "auto",       "break",      "case",       "cast",
      "character",  "comment",    "compiler",   "constant",   "continue",
      "default",    "double",     "dynamic",    "else",       "enum",
      "expression", "extern",     "file",       "float",      "function",
      "goto",       "heap",       "identifier", "library",    "linker",
      "long",       "macro",      "operand",    "operator",   "pointer",
      "prototype",  "recursion",  "register",   "return",     "short",
      "signed",     "sizeof",     "stack",      "statement",  "static",
      "string",     "struct",     "switch",     "typedef",    "union",
      "unsigned",   "variable",   "void",       "volatile",   "while"
   };

    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomNumber;
    randomNumber = rand() %51;
    printf("%d\n", randomNumber);
    int wordLength = strlen(words[randomNumber]);
    printf("%d %s\n", wordLength, words[randomNumber]);
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What's the correct syntax to call the 'init' method in the main method?

Comment: for a start you should call init() with a `char *` as an argument. i have a feeling you want this to run in a loop. 

`init("notinlist");`

Comment: `init(word);` is how you call. But I don't see how you would use it though. Describe your problem and what the function `init` is supposed to do.

Comment: Init contains an array of words. I am trying choose one at random, print the random number that was generated, the word from the array that the random number correlates too and the length of that word.

Comment: Right. To do that, why would need to pass something to `init()`?

Comment: Well it is the problem as stated by @BlueMoon and also  MAX_WORD_LEN  and ALPHABET_SIZE are not defined in this code and also the header file shouldn't they be in  like this <stdio.h> format.

Comment: They are defined in the header file hangman.h. I am not sure what needs to be passed to init.

Comment: @Luke No need to pass anything you can just put parameters as void.

Comment: @ameyCU does the declaration need to also change?

Comment: @Luke yes ,if not sure what to pass then declare it like this **`void init(void);` **

Comment: thank you, will have a fiddle now.

Comment: Error at the decleration: "Error: Conflicting types of 'init'"
Error at method call: "too many arguments to function 'init'"

Comment: Other than the method call/decleration, can anyone see any other problems with the code?

Comment: I'd also recommend that, if you're going to write C code, stop calling them methods.  They're called Functions.  Methods are found on objects. :)

Comment: Please don't call as method a C function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not name your function 'init' if it is not designed for initializing anything. Name it `getRandomWord` instead, or something likethat.

Your `words` array contains 50 items, so its valid indices span the range 0 till 49. Consequently you should truncate your `rand()` result modulo 50, not 51. Anyway it's safer to use a predefined macro for a constant:

```
int randomNumber = rand() % NUM_WORDS;
```

**ADDED**

You can also drop the size at all and make the compiler calculate it when needed. Then you can freely add new words in future versions without updating `NUM_WORDS` definition: This is the trick: take the size of array (in bytes) and divide it by the size of the array item.

```
const char* words[] = {  // size defined implicitly by a words list
  "array",      "auto",       "break",      "case",       "cast"
  // .....
};

int num_words = sizeof words / sizeof words[0];
int randomNumber = rand() % num_words;
```

(End of 'added'.)

Use `srand()` once, `rand()` multiple times:

```
main()
{
    char word[ MAX_WORD_LEN + 1];

    // some preparations
    .....
    srand( time(NULL) );

    // main work

    while( still_want_to_work )
    {
        getRandomWord( word );
        processTheWord( word ); // eg. print it
    }
}
```

Then `getRandomWord(char *word)` may deliver a random word to the caller:

```
void getRandomWord(char* word)
{
    const char* words[] = {
      "array",      "auto",       "break",      "case",       "cast"
      //......
   };

    int randomNumber = rand() % (sizeof words / sizeof words[0]);
    printf("%d\n", randomNumber);
    int wordLength = strlen(words[randomNumber]);
    printf("%d %s\n", wordLength, words[randomNumber]);

    // copy the word to a buffer prepared by a caller
    strncpy( word, words[randomNumber], MAX_WORD_LEN );
    // and terminate the result in case the source is too long
    word[MAX_WORD_LEN] = 0;
}
```

Comment: @Luke See what I added. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `init` as function with parameter `char*` , but calling it without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Modify you function prototype as well as definition from `void init(char * word)` to `void init()` since you already have `const char* words[NUM_WORDS]` defined inside your function, you don't need to pass any arguments.

Comment: "Error number of arguments doesn't match prototype"

Comment: don't only modify the prototype, modify the function definition too, accordingly.